# Find prime number so that two rings are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra

For $p$ prime number, let $I=\langle x^3-x\rangle$  and $J=\langle x^3+x\rangle$ be ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ and consider the rings $R=\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/I$ and $S=\mathbb{Z}_p[x]/J$ and the polynomial $f(x)=x^2+x+1 \in \mathbb{Z}_p[x]$.

1. Find prime number $p$ so that $f(x)+I$ is invertible in $R$.
2. Find prime number $p$ so that $f(x)+J$ is invertible in $S$.
3. Find prime number $p>2$ so that the rings $R,S$ are isomorphic.

So far for the first one I showed that for $f(x)+I$ to be invertible in each ring it suffices to show that the greatest common divisor $(x^2+x+1, x^3-x)=1$ and so $p \equiv 1\pmod{3}$.
For the second I have that the greatest common divisor $(x^2+x+1, x^3+x)=1$ in any case, using Euclidean algorithm of polynomial division.

For the third question, I should use the first isomorphism theorem of rings, but I have no clue how to use to it here. I think that I should use something from the first two questions, but still no idea.

Comment: $\mathbf Z_p$ is the ring of $p$-adic integers?

Comment: Yes, and $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ is the ring of ponynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Comment: $x^3-x=x(x-1)(x+1)$ and $x^2+x+1=1,3,1$ for $x=0,1,-1$. Therefore, for every prime different from $3$ the gcd of $x^2+x+1$ and $x^3-x$ is going to be $1$. The $p\equiv1\mod{3}$ excludes too many primes.

Comment: Are you sure you intend that to mean $p$-adic integers? It seems to me you want integers modulo p

Comment: Actually integers modulo p (not quite adapted to translate terms in algebra)